# max_binlog_files on MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, binlog

I read recently about a setting in Percona Server called `max_binlog_files` which restricts the total number of binlog files.  This is exactly what I need.  My `binlog_expire_logs_seconds` is currently set to 3 days, which works great 99% of the time.  However, I'm currently engaged in project which runs a massive amount of queries and the binlogs grew to consume over 70GB in just a few hours.  In this case, I really need to limit the number of files.

Is there any native setting with MySQL to achieve this? What is the best way to restrict total disk space consumed by binlogs?

Comment: Big `UPDATEs` or `DELETEs` can cause lots of binlog entries.  Perhaps we should discuss alternatives.  What were your commands?  Here are some tips to avoid binlog-bloat when doing [_Big deletes_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) .  (And help the deletes run faster.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the upstream MySQL implementation does not have a feature equivalent to `max_binlog_files`. So you can't really prevent a short-term surge in binary log growth.

Well, the option `log_bin=OFF` would definitely prevent unlimited binary log growth, but that's the only solution provided by stock MySQL Server.

You could implement a scheduled job outside of MySQL (e.g. a cron job) to periodically check `SHOW BINARY LOGS` and if they are using more space than you want, then `PURGE BINARY LOGS` to reduce the space.

The risk is that your aggressive purging might delete some logs that are still needed for replication, point-in-time recovery, or CDC tools, if you use those features.

At my last job, we occasionally had binary logs on a given MySQL grow to 500GB. The developers were not aware of the impact of doing huge bulk data loads, and they would do so anytime they felt like it, without notifying the DBA team. We were using Percona Server so we set a `max_binlog_files=500` so they wouldn't use *more* than 500GB, but we weren't at liberty to be more restrictive.

Ultimately, we just had to make sure there was enough storage space free on each database server for these kinds of surges.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the input. I'm not generally concerned about replication or point in time recovery in this case so a cron job it is!  I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Why do you have binary logs enabled at all, if you don't use them?

Comment: Aren't they used for transactions...?

Comment: No, the binary log is not used for transactions. You might be thinking of the [InnoDB redo log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-redo-log.html), which has fixed size. It doesn't grow (unless you enable the new redo log archiving feature).

Comment: The redo log is for crash recovery. The binary log is not used for that.

Comment: It's starting to sound like `log_bin=OFF` is your best solution! :-)

Comment: An aside, you can use SQL_LOG_BIN=0 to turn off binlogging for a session in MySQL; tell your developers to do that before they load huge amounts of test data.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n, What you say would work if the developers remember to do it. But I wouldn't trust them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In light of the helpful answer by @BillKarwin, I opted to have cron run a simple bash script at 15 minute intervals. I'm not very good with bash so there might be a more succinct way, but for now this seems to be getting the job done:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
MAX_BINLOG_FILES=50
PURGE_TO_LOG=$(mysql -e "SHOW BINARY LOGS" | tac | sed "${MAX_BINLOG_FILES}q;d" | awk '{print $1}')
if [ ! -z "$PURGE_TO_LOG" ] 
then
    mysql -e "PURGE BINARY LOGS TO '$PURGE_TO_LOG'"
fi
```

Comment: Keep in mind that not every binary log has the maximum size. They can start new log files when the server restarts, or when someone runs `FLUSH LOGS`. Some of the binlog files may be small. To make this more bulletproof, you should really sum up the sizes of the respective files, and purge only if the sum is greater than what you want.

Comment: And I guess you're okay with the risk that your replicas are lagging behind, and you might inadvertently break replication by deleting a binlog file that is still needed.

Comment: Regarding your first point, yes I am aware.  I considered doing a filesize sum, but in this case since I'm purging back to 50 logs I suspect that will be fine since I normally only see the last couple of binlogs with smaller size.  Is it ever the case that there are more than 2 or 3 under max size?  In a more active production situation I agree, checking sum of sizes would be best.

Comment: Sure, I've seen cases where a server was restarted repeatedly in a short time, and all the binlog files were small.